# Stop SKAudioNode from Playing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to play footstep sounds only when the player is moving. I added a check to see if the player is already moving to make sure it would not play audio on top of each other.

For some reason `footstepSound.run(SKAction.stop())` is not working which is causing a bunch of tracks to play over each other which sounds very bad.

Any ideas?

```
        let footstepSound = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "Footsteps.mp3")
        if (degree != 50) {
            if (isFootstepping) { return }
            isFootstepping = true
            self.addChild(footstepSound)
        }
        else if (isFootstepping && degree == 50) {
            isFootstepping = false
            footstepSound.run(SKAction.stop())
            footstepSound.removeFromParent()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The issue is that the footstepSound variable was not globally declared. This was causing a new variable to be created on each function call, therefore when .removeFromParent was called it was never referencing the old variable.